# Tirando barra de rolagem Tabs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Preciso remover a barra de rolagem que esta nos tabs, ele gerou uma barra de rolagem e quero que ela fique estática como fazer ?

Tentei utilizar `overflow-y:hidden` porem não funcionou.

```
<ul id="tabss" style="text-align: center;" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#bio" data-toggle="tab">Biografia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#noticias" data-toggle="tab">Últimas Notícias</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#agendas" data-toggle="tab">Agendas</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#recados" data-toggle="tab">Recados</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="bio">Bio</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="noticias">Noticias</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="agendas">Agendas</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="recados">Recados</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#tabss {  
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-top: 36vh;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 999; 
}
#tabss li {   text-decoration: none; display: inline; padding: 5px; }
#tabss a { color: black; text-align: center; }
#tabss a:hover { color: #AE0823; }
.tab-content {   z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  height: 20vw;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 40vh;
  opacity: 0.80;
}
#bio {   margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 35px; }
```

Comment: Você colocou o `overflow-y: hidden;` em qual seletor CSS?

Comment: no tab-contant.

Comment: Veja se isso te ajuda em alguma coisa: [http://codigosphp.blogspot.com.br/2008/06/retirar-barra-de-rolagem-com-css.html](http://adf.ly/1K7cFT)
<br>Não sou um 'mestre' em css3 mas acho que isso te servirá em algo!

Comment: Consegue reproduzir o problema em um [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @falsarella não consigo pois muita coisas em php interna, e nao intendo muito de fiddle

Comment: Não da ja tentei olhar isto na internet.

Comment: Bom, provavelmente está aplicando o `overflow-y:hidden` no elemento errado, ou de forma errada. Fica complicado ajudar com mais precisão sem ter mais detalhes. Já tentou inspecionar pelo navegador?

Comment: sim, mais nada aparece.

Comment: Deveria aparecer pelo menos o overflow. Tem certeza de que escreveu o seletor CSS certinho?

Comment: Me passe o css q está usando, talvez eu possa te ajudar melhor!

Comment: @NickolasCarlos ja conseguir solucionar, pode ver a resposta logo abaixo. Mas  mesmo assim obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução estava no arquivo `bootstrap.css`, tinha uma linha de código:

```
.tab-content {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

assim passei ela para:

```
.tab-content {
  overflow: none;
}
```

> Obrigado a todos que me ajudarão.